# java - add two textbox values and display the sum in a label automatically

Tags: java, netbeans

[sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gbk75.jpg)

label = price * qty

I want to display price and qty multiplication in label automatically without any button click.

After enter price value and qty value to textboxes

I use netbeans and java langauge only. how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using netbeanse IDE which provides user interface for using java Frames. You can easily right click on the second textfield go to the events and add a keyreleased event listerner. This will automatically direct your towards the generated method where you can write something like this

```
 int value = Integer.parseInt(Textfield1.gettext())*Integer.parseInt(Textfield2.gettext());
 Label.settext(String.valueof(value));
```

What it will do that if both text fields are non empty then it will set the result on the lable after releasing the key on textfield2, else it'll throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void Met(JTextField x) {
    x.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEve`enter code here`nt e) {
           double result;
               result =price * qty;
          txtResult.setText(result+"");
        }
    });
}
```

first you need this method in the code, then in the constructor of your JFrame call this method and put your txtqty as argument, after that when you write something in the qty txt will do your operation, of course you need to put the value of the price and qty taking the values of the boxes and you will need to protect for the exceptions that can be appear

Comment: You need this on both text fields so result will change every time you type number in any of them.

Comment: yep that's right just be care full if one of the boxes is empty because it will have an exception so just protect with an if or catching the exception, or throwing, as you wish